# Sending email from domain name address

Tags: email, smtp, domain-name, alias

hey, I've just bought a domain name and would like to send emails from blah@mydomain.com. I can use an alias from my hotmail/gmail account, but the recipient sometimes sees it as
"my@hotmail.com on behalf of blah@mydomain.com". Is there a way to only show "blah@mydomain.com"? Any free SMTP servers I can setup/use? thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of spam, most (if not all) ISP and email providers will not allow you to spoof an email using their SMTP servers.

You will need to sign up for a hosted email package which will provide you with an SMTP server for use with your domain.

The registrar of your domain may offer such a package.

If not there are many hosting providers which offer email only packages.

One non-free option is to sign up for a [Google Workspace](https://workspace.google.com) (formerly Google G Suite, formerly Google Apps) account which gives you a full Gmail account (also Google Docs, Google Calendar and more) but using your domain instead of @gmail.com

Comment: good option on the google apps account +1

Comment: +1 for a good answer, and the recommendation of Google Apps standard.

Comment: I believe google charges for every single account on the g-suite, no?  Can you confirm that one can use any address on a domain with g-suite without creating further (paying) accounts?

Comment: @SteveHorvath yes they do charge per mailbox. However you can set up multiple aliases to that mailbox

Comment: I am lucky enough to have one of the grandfathered free G Suite accounts before they went paid, so I couldn't tell you if they charge for additional aliases now though

Comment: its 30 aliases per user